# Can't deploy streamlit app on share.streamlit.io

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, streamlit, requirements.txt

I am working with a simple ML model with streamlit. It runs fine on my local machine inside conda environment, but it shows **Error installing requirements** when I try to deploy it on share.streamlit.io.
The error message is the following:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==303 (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==303
```

This is the requirements.txt file for my model:

```
altair==4.1.0
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
astor==0.8.1
attrs==21.2.0
backcall==0.2.0
base58==2.1.1
bleach==4.1.0
blinker==1.4
cachetools==5.0.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.9
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.4
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.5.1
decorator==5.1.0
defusedxml==0.7.1
entrypoints==0.3
fonttools==4.28.5
gitdb==4.0.9
GitPython==3.1.24
idna==3.3
ipykernel==6.6.0
ipython==7.30.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.6.5
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
joblib==1.1.0
jsonschema==4.3.2
jupyter-client==7.1.0
jupyter-core==4.9.1
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.2
kiwisolver==1.3.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.5.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
mistune==0.8.4
nbclient==0.5.9
nbconvert==6.3.0
nbformat==5.1.3
nest-asyncio==1.5.4
notebook==6.4.6
numpy==1.21.5
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.3.5
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.4.0
prometheus-client==0.12.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.24
protobuf==3.19.1
pyarrow==6.0.1
pycparser==2.21
pydeck==0.7.1
Pygments==2.10.0
Pympler==1.0.1
pyparsing==3.0.6
pyrsistent==0.18.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
pywin32==303
pywinpty==1.1.6
pyzmq==22.3.0
requests==2.26.0
scikit-learn==1.0.1
scipy==1.7.3
seaborn==0.11.2
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
smmap==5.0.0
streamlit==1.3.0
terminado==0.12.1
testpath==0.5.0
threadpoolctl==3.0.0
toml==0.10.2
toolz==0.11.2
tornado==6.1
traitlets==5.1.1
typing_extensions==4.0.1
tzdata==2021.5
tzlocal==4.1
urllib3==1.26.7
validators==0.18.2
watchdog==2.1.6
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.2
wincertstore==0.2
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streamlit share runs the app in a linux environment meaning there is no pywin32 because this is for windows.

Delete the pywin32 from the requirements file and also the pywinpty==1.1.6 for the same reason.

After deleting these requirements re-deploy your app and it will work.

Comment: This solved the issue! Thanks a lot for the help.